# GWT serialization of a subclass

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-platform

I have RPC service that returns an object of type GameEvent that 
extends from Event (abstract). When I get the object on the client 
side, all the properties inherited from Event (eventId, copyEventId, 
gameTimeGMT) are set to `null` whereas on the server side, these 
properties have values.

```
public class GameEvent extends Event implements IsSerializable { 
    private String homeTeam; 
    private String awayTeam; 
    public GameEvent() { 
    } 
} 

// Annotation are from the twig-persist framework which should not 
// impact the serialization process. 
public abstract class Event implements IsSerializable { 
    @Key 
    protected String eventId; 
    @Index 
    protected String copyEventId; 
    protected Date gameTimeGMT; 
    protected Event() { 
    }
}
```

Update: I use the gwt-platform framework (MVP implementation). Here is the call to the service client side. The `result.getGE()` returns the GameEvent object but with `null` properties.

```
dispatcher.execute(
        new GetFormattedEventAction(
                id),
        new AsyncCallback<GetFormattedEventResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                caught.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(
                    GetFormattedEventResult result) {
                FormattedGameEvent formattedGameEvent = new FormattedGameEvent(
                        result.getGE());
            }
        });
```

The action handler:

```
public class GetFormattedEventActionHandler implements
        ActionHandler<GetFormattedEventAction, GetFormattedEventResult> {

    @Override
    public GetFormattedEventResult execute(GetFormattedEventAction action,
            ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {
        GameEvent gameEvent = null;
        QueryResultIterator<GameEvent> rs = datastore.find().type(
                GameEvent.class).addFilter("copyEventId", FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                action.getEventId()).returnResultsNow();
        if (rs.hasNext()) {
            gameEvent = rs.next();
        }
        return new GetFormattedEventResult(gameEvent);
    }
}
```

The Result:

```
public class GetFormattedEventResult implements Result {

    private GameEvent e;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GetFormattedEventResult() {
    }

    public GetFormattedEventResult(GameEvent gameEvent) {
        e = gameEvent;
    }

    public GameEvent getGE() {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to take a stab.

Verify that the Event class is in the GWT serialization whitelist (the `.gwt.rpc` file that is generated for each service interface). If it's not, you may have to [trick GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138099/how-do-i-add-a-type-to-gwts-serialization-policy-whitelist) into adding it.

Comment: Updated the question. Also tried to trick GWT but it's not working.

Comment: The GameEvent had properties of a type that did not implement IsSerializable, that's why it was not in the serialization whitelist.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.  GWTC should have issued a warning about that, though.

Comment: Was a solution found or not?  And what was it?  I am facing the same problem now and am curious of how you solved your problem.